# PhoneGap inAppBrowser loadstop event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

My page is very simple.
When it's running, only shows one button. When clicking the button, inAppBrowser is opened and a page "1.html" is loaded. There is also a button in 1.html, click it will turn to 2.html.
My goal:
1. After click the button on 1.html, it will turn to 2.html (done).
2. Every time the url in inAppBrowser is changed, alert the url. 
Here is the code of index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser.addEventListener Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            var ref = window.open('1.html', '_blank', 'location=yes');
            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
        });
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is one button on "1.html". If it is clicked, turn to "2.html".
Here is the code of 1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function(){
            $('#btn').click(function(){
                window.href.location = '2.html';
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">Test</button>
    <div id="msg"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Every time inAppBrowser url is changed. Does this trigger loadstop event? If yes, why I can't get it work. If no, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether the plugin for inappbrowser is correctly configured in the config.xml. This can be verified in the online phonegap build section or in the config.xml.

The configuration for android in config.xml is:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problem and that was the solution. I was confused, because `window.open` seemed to be working without adding this plugin. But it is needed to handle events!

Answer (score 0):

In `1.html`, change the code from `window.href.location = '2.html';` to `window.location.href = '2.html';`. Then when you are on 1.html and click the button, it will actually change the URL and alert the new URL.